# Convert the time format in php

Tags: php, date, time

How would I convert a date formatted like this
`Thu, 08 Jul 2010 15:51:01` into a date like this `Thursday July 8th, 2010 3:51 pm`. Also, how would I filter the first sting to not include time, so that it could look like this in the end `Thursday July 8th, 2010`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://pl2.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
echo date("l F jS, Y", strtotime("Thu, 08 Jul 2010 15:51:01"));
```

Comment: Thanks, works great. I looked at the manual for awhile before and it wasn't working. I was missing the strtotime part.

Answer (score 1):

you can take a look at all of the possible date formatting options here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Basically, with the date() function you construct a date in any format you want, for example

```
echo date('l M d, Y');
```

would output Thursday Apr 29, 2010