# Time Format : PHP

Tags: php, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Covert time format in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2741153/covert-time-format-in-php)

I am getting a start_time field value  from mysql  data base as `2012-08-14 21:30:00`

and i  want to convert it in php  format like 2012-08-14T09:30   is there any method to do

this in php ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [strtotime()](http://www.php.net/strtotime)

```
$date = strtotime('2012-08-14 21:30:00');
echo date('Y-m-d\Th:i',$date);
```

Comment: But that'll give the time in 24 hour format

Comment: nope ... `h` is for 12 hour format, [reference](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php)

Comment: sorry didn't notice that. i was searching for `a` (am/pm)

Answer (score 0):

see this example.for the required date & time format:

```
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");//get the current date
$d=strtotime($date);//convert in strtotime
echo $final_date=date("Y-m-d\Th:i:s",$d);//in the first argument of date ,put the format whatever you want,but be sure to convert it in strtotime first.
```